# Generating APK - gradlew is not recognised

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Trying to generate signed APK for android using windows 10, I have generated my keystore but how do I run `gradlew assembleRelease`?

I have unzipped the binary into C:, added gradle to my `path`. However, `gradlew` is not recognised, and there is no `build.gradle` file in `android/app/`

The `react native` docs aren't very clear at all. Can anyone help?

Using `Android Studio` I cannot see any build options either.

[image]

Tried `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` but get the error  `'&&' is not a valid statement separator`

Menu in android studio looks like:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to "Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files" properly?

Comment: I cannot see the Android option,

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am using a Mac, it's the same on windows too: you can use the Build->Generate signed APK. That should work by default. If that it's not working I suggest to Invalidate caches and restart your android studio.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I don't see those options under Build

Comment: can you add a screenshooy of your android studio top buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your react native project directory and run

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```